# Regex to target last two spaces in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex newbie here. I'm trying to write an expression that matches the last two (or n) separate spaces.

```
       v v
This is a test
```

I have an ultra simple expression that returns the last space:
`/ (?=[^ ]*$)/i`
but cannot seem to figure out how to get it to return twice and only twice (or n times)

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: No output on the regex, but I'm using a replace function to add non-breaking spaces to a string to eliminate widows.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookahead that will require that there are not two spaces somewhere after the candidate space:

```js
let s = "This is a test";

let result = s.replace(/ (?!.* .* )/gs, "°");

console.log(result);
```

I must say that this has a bad time complexity. For large strings you will get better performance with `lastIndexOf`:

```js
let s = "This is a test";

s = "  " + s; // Add dummies to avoid boundary cases
let last = s.lastIndexOf(" ");
let prev = s.lastIndexOf(" ", last - 1);

// Replace those spaces:
let result = s.slice(0, prev) + "°" + s.slice(prev+1, last) + "°" + s.slice(last+1);
// Remove the dummies:
result = result.slice(2);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also match a space and assert using a positive lookahead that there is an optional space to the right.

<sup>Denoted the space between square brackets just for clarity.</sup>

```
[ ](?=(?:\S+ ){0,1}\S+$)
```

- `[ ]` Match a space
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert that on the right it

  - `(?:\S+ ){0,1}` Match 0 or 1 non whitespace chars followed by a space
  - `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars
  - `$` End of string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/haPum1/1)

In the pattern, the quantifier `{0,1}` lets you specify the amount of spaces to match.

Using `{0,2}` will [match the last 3 spaces](https://regex101.com/r/ykp62E/1), and using `{0}` will match only the last space.

If there can also be optional spaces at the end:

```
[ ](?=(?:\S+ ){0,1}\S+ *$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s34NDf/1)